# Drag along movieclip with ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I drag object (a movieclip) along BG (also a movieclip).
Moving/dragging object (movieclip) inside BG?

```
BG.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, DRAG);
BG.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, DROP);

function DRAG (e:MouseEvent) {
 object.x = e.localX;
 object.y = e.localY;
 //object.startDrag();

 //code to drag object(movieclip) along BG(movieclip)
}
function DROP (e:MouseEvent) {
 object.stopDrag();
 object.x = 0;
 object.y = 0;
}
```

Edited/New Code:

```
//bg(movieclip)
//obj(movieclip to drag)
//object2(movieclip)

var bounds: Rectangle = new Rectangle();
bounds.x = bg.x;
bounds.y = bg.y;
bounds.width = bg.width - obj.width;
bounds.height = bg.height - obj.height;

object2.x = obj.x;
object2.y = obj.y;

object2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, Drag);
object2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, Drop);

function Drag(event: TouchEvent): void {
    object2.x = e.LocalX;
    object2.y = e.LocalY;
    e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);

    obj.x = e.localX;       
    obj.x = e.localY;   
    obj.startDrag(false, bounds);
}

function Drop(event: TouchEvent): void {
    End_Drag();
}

public function End_Drag():void {
    obj.stopDrag();
    obj.x = bound.x;
    obj.y = bound.y;

    object2.stopTouchDrag(object2.touchPointID);
    object.x = bound.x;
    object.y = bound.y; 
}
```

I seperate the stop-drag event function because it may be called in different class.

In my edited code, When I 'TOUCH_DOWN' object2, both obj and object2 changed it position to where I 'TOUCH_DOWN' and it didn't drag them. And when I 'TOUCH_END' object2, it reset their position.

P.S. This codes are for my Virtual JoyStick Controller.

Comment: What does it means "along BG"? Object should not go beyond BG?

Comment: yes, it should always hit the movieclip 'BG'. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, too. Within several minutes I'll give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two objects: background `bg` and object `obj` that you want to drag.
[image: Screenshot]

Define the rectangle area. Object can be moved only inside this area.

```
var bounds: Rectangle = new Rectangle();
bounds.x = bg.x;
bounds.y = bg.y;
bounds.width = bg.width - obj.width;
bounds.height = bg.height - obj.height;
```

Start moving an `obj` when the mouse down. Stop moving after mouse is up anywhere.

```
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objDown);

function objDown(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    obj.startDrag(false, bounds);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
}

function mouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    //smooth moving
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function mouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    obj.stopDrag();

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var bounds: Rectangle = new Rectangle();
bounds.x = bg.x;
bounds.y = bg.y;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 

obj1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, objTouchBegin);
obj2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, objTouchBegin);

function objTouchBegin(event: TouchEvent): void
{
    bounds.width = bg.width - event.currentTarget.width;
    bounds.height = bg.height - event.currentTarget.height;

    event.currentTarget.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, bounds);

    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, touchMove);
}

function touchMove(event:TouchEvent): void
{
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function touchEnd(event: TouchEvent): void
{
    event.currentTarget.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);

    stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);
    stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, touchMove);
}
```

Comment: Thank for sharing this code but I changed MouseEvent to TouchEvent because the game is for mobile devices. But, I still used you code, no error but there's a problem. When i clicked/tap another button(movieclip) while dragging the object, the object stop drag-event that it shouldn't.

Comment: i have an idea how i'm going to deal with but my code seems wrong because it can not drag the object. I'll edit my question to add my code, will you please check it. thank you.

Comment: Thanks and I ll  try this. But, will it stop drag-event if I click/Tap the stage while dragging the obj1 or obj2?

Comment: No, It'll not stop. Also you can drag two objects with two fingers.

Comment: Hi. I tested my App with your code and there's a problem. When I 'TOUCH_END' another point while dragging the object, it stop dragging the object..

Comment: Hi. It's weird. I tested on my iPhone. All works. If you capture the video I will try to help you.

Comment: Attach your FLA. I'll try to run it on my iPhone.

Comment: The whole FLA file is almost 300mb, and I don't know how to attach it? but i really copy your code(copy - paste) and change only the name of variables.